# modular reduction algorithm over $F_{2^m}$ doesn't seem to work when order of polynomial being reduced is small

Tags: finite-field, gcm

I was considering [algorithm 2.40 (arbitrary reduction polynomials)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFr7Z.png) in the [Guide to Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://www.springeronline.com/sgw/cda/pageitems/document/cda_downloaddocument/0,11996,0-0-45-110359-0,00.pdf#page=29) and...  it doesn't appear to work when the order of the polynomial you're trying to reduce is less than the order of the reduction polynomial.

Say you have a reduction polynomial of $x^{128}+x^7+x^2+x^1+1$ (the GCM reduction polynomial) and are trying to reduce $x^{127}$.

With polynomial division the quotient is $0$ and the remainder is $x^{127}$ but algorithm 2.40 in the ... seems to give $0$ as the answer.

In the for loop $i$ is going from the $2m - 2$'th bit (more specifically, the coefficient of $x^i$) downto the $m$'th, where $m$ is the order of the reduction polynomial ($128$). So you never actually get to $x^{127}$ and so nothing is ever added to $C\{j\}$ and thus the return value is $0$.

Is my analysis correct? If so that would seem to imply that the algorithm given n the Guide to Elliptic Curve Cryptography is insufficient and it's inclusion probably ought to be considered errata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the for loop $i$ is going from the $2m - 2$'th bit (more specifically, the coefficient of $x^i$) downto the $m$'th, where $m$ is the order of the reduction polynomial ($128$). So you never actually get to $x^{127}$ and so nothing is ever added to $C\{j\}$ and thus the return value is $0$.

Actually, $C$ starts off initialized to the input polynomial $c(z)$, and so by not adding anything, the final $C$ value is precisely the initial value, which is the correct answer.

They could have written the algorithm clearer by explicitly stating that, and using the same case for $C$ consistently...